# How to use a DLL create from txt and compiled with Developer Command Prompt?

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, using

I generate cs files ( classes ) with the same namespace (EDR_Config). After I generate them, I compile them using Developer Command Prompt for VS2012.

The command line is :
             `csc /target:library /out:EDR_Config.DLL AssemblyInfo.cs 
            EdrClassInitializator_CFG.cs EdrEquationsDecoder_CFG.cs EdrTreeCreator_CFG.cs`

Everything looks great till I add a reference to the c# project. When I try to write
`using EDR_Config;`
it tell me: Error   1   The type or namespace name 'EDR_Config' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Why is that happening? Or how can I solve it?

Comment: Please show a short but complete example. Are any of your classes public? If not, that would explain it. (I would strongly recommend against those filenames and that namespace, by the way - something like `EDR.Configuration` as the namespace would be more idiomatic, with filenames of just `Initializer`, `EquationsDecoder` etc.

Comment: forgot to put the class public... i thought it wouldn't affect it... thx